# Google Play Console

Tags: android, visual-studio, google-play-console

tengo una pregunta , es la primera ves usando o queriendo publicar una app en "Google Play Console" me gustaría saber como bajar mi archivo abb. ya que quiero actualizar ciertas cosas para la publicación y revisión , Ojala me ayuden por favor

Comment: Hola. ¿No tienes el código fuente, en Android Studio o donde sea que hayas desarrollado la aplicación? Debes actualizar ese código fuente, aumentar en `1` el número de versión, generar un nuevo `.abb` firmado y subirlo a Google Play Console. Por cierto, convendría que tengas una copia de tu código fuente en otro sitio, por ejemplo en un repositorio remoto tipo Github, pero no subas ahí archivos sensibles, como tu key store, las APIs de Google Services, etc.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, agrega más información a tu pregunta, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Perdonen por hacer una pregunta tan sencilla o tan pobre pero es la primera ves que pregunto , aun asi muchas gracias por su paciencia
Lo que quiero en si es bajar el .abb de google play console porque no me deja subir uno nuevo

Comment: @JMGil agrega una imagen al menos de donde lo quieres bajar, saludos